# How use tune2fs in with dd?

Tags: filesystems, dd

In [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Cloning) tutorial is written:

> To regain unique UUIDs, use `tune2fs /dev/sdbX -U random` on every partition.

Ok, but how can I use it with this command?

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

Or do I have to use it after the `dd` command?

Comment: Note that if you have e2fsprogs 1.42.9 or later, you can use `e2image` instead of `dd` and it will be much faster as it skips unused blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use it after the `dd` commmand. Because you've copied over the partition table, you'll need to first inform the kernel of the change, e.g., by running `partprobe /dev/sdb`.

Basically, what's happening is that there is a unique value (a UUID) stored in filesystem metadata. When you copy whole partitions (as you're doing with `dd`), you wind up with two partitions (and thus two filesystems) with the same UUID. So much for it being unique! This is a problem if, e.g., you try to use a UUID to mount the filesystem.

In order to fix the problem, you change the UUID on the copy—that `tune2fs` line does so. You need to run it on each partition on the destination disk that contains a ext2/3/4 filesystem. You'll need different utilities for other filesystem types.

Comment: Ok, so after that I use dd comamnd, is have to use       tune2fs /dev/sdbX -U random only in output file (of=) HD? Or I have use in all HD, (if=) and (of=)?

Comment: @VitorMazuco well, you'll need to put in partition numbers in place of X, but yes. And you need to run partprobe first. So, dd, then partprobe, then tune2fs.